# How to create phone app that will download external resources depeding on configuration or what user chooses

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap

We have an app and we need to maintain several versions of this app, because of our customers.
GooglePlay prohibits and rejects such apps because it thinks they are too similar and there should only be one version in the Play shop.
The apps are written in Cordova.

How to create an app that when opened, depending on the configuration or selecting appropriate version (this we know how to do).

It would download additional files depending on the version required. (like games downloading external sources every update - games need updating from shop, but also downloading external resources internally after starting)

Comment: Well you know what has to be done. What exactly is the problem doing so?

Comment: @blackapps Not sure If its possible and can't find option in cordova how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read about [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/ProductFlavor).

Comment: You can just provide the link in the comment of the question rather than posting answer for it.

Comment: Well, I don't have enough reputation for it :) @RudrikPatel